Fast way to delete packages in github (Docker image builds)
So I'm using the Github Actions to build an image which I can use in Docker. As the project I'm working on was not really well prepared for this, I had to do a lot of tests and this project is pretty large*, so we're burning storage pretty quickly.
How can I delete all packages with 'build-test' in the name?
v2.191.0
v0.build-test.78   <-- I want this removed
v0.build-test.77   <-- I want this removed
v0.build-test.76   <-- I want this removed
v2.190.0
v0.build-test.75   <-- I want this removed
v2.189.0
v2.188.0
v0.build-test.74   <-- I want this removed
v0.build-test.73   <-- I want this removed
v2.187.0
v2.186.0

Doing this manually is taking forever, because I have to click 'options', then 'delete' and then paste my project name.  I might also want to delete all the "normal" builds as they're not functional either.
In the Github cli I cant find anything like gh packages or anything and the API example I found doesnt appear to be working.
I also cant find anything to delete a package via gh.
The exact pattern using something like awk/grep is not an issue (but might be nice for the next person).

* Yes I know images should be as small as possible. That is a work in progress. First image building, than improving.
